# How do you open the Gallery App from an app?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an app that takes screenshots and saves them to an album in the iOS gallery app. I want to be able to open the gallery app from my app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry not possible. Some apps allow you to open them from within your app using URL schemes but the built in iOS photos app is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to see the photo album is by creating a `UIImagePickerController` and setting its source type as `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`. This will open it in album view inside the app. I am not sure whether that satisfies your requirement completely.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

Alternatively you can also check [asset library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730) and the [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010135)

Comment: Is there any way to email an image from the picker or view an image in fullscreen, swipe to go to the next image, etc.?

Comment: I would suggest you to look at asset library for this. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730 .. There is a sample code as https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010135